# Find the time interval with max number of concurrent processes

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

A system generates logs in format: startTime, endTime, Request.
How to calculate the interval with max number of concurrent requests?
I tried using hashmap with time stamp as key request count as value. Populate keys with all values between start and time for each request and update counter, but this will require huge space, if time stamp is precise up to milliseconds.

Comment: Maybe take a look at Guava's RangeMap.

Comment: Scan from left to right, keeping track of the number of unterminated intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the list to events with the properties ts, value

startTime: 123456, endTime:23456, Request: .... becomes two events:

(123456, 1)
(23456, -1)

You'll now have 2x the number of requests as events.

If you sort those events by timestamp you can iterate over them adding and subtracting the values. Keep track of the largest value you saw and the timestamp it occurred at.

This runs in O(nlogn) since you need to sort the events and takes O(n) space.